# semantic-ui segment is not covering the whole menu when menu fixed to top

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to create a menu fixed to the top of the page:

```
<Segment inverted>
   <Menu fixed = "top" inverted pointing
       secondary stackable size="large" >
     <Container>
       <Menu.Item as="a" name="Item1">
       <Menu.Item as="a" name="Item2">
     </Container>
   </Menu>
</Segment>
```

When the Menu fixed to top the surrounding Segment is sized smaller than the embedded Menu (and also not fixed to top).

What's the proper way to do it?

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/szert/pen/ayrbRj)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `secondary` and `inverted` at the same time.
If you remove `secondary` attribute, I think you'll see the results.

Also you can add a custom class to the content `Segment` so if the `Menu` is fixed, adding a `margin-top: 32px;` (or any size you want) to the content `Segment`.